# CSS td conditional background color setting

Tags: css, angular, html-table, conditional-statements, background-color

Suppose I have the following angular table

```
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let company of investTable; let i = index">
      <td>
       {{company.name}}
      </td>
      <td>
       {{company.price}}
      </td>
      <td>
       {{company.profit}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

How can I make a neat solution to have table cells have a background color depending on the cell value ? lets say if company profit is positive, make it green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in css

```
td.highlight {
  background-color: green;
}
```

in html :-

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let company of investTable; let i = index">
      <td>
       {{company.price}}
      </td>
      <td [ngClass]="{'highlight': company.profit > 0}">
       {{company.profit}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) and [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). Simplest use case would be to directly bind to the `style` property.

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let company of investTable; let i = index">
    <td>
      {{company.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{company.price}}
    </td>
    <td [style.background-color]="company?.profit > 5 ? 'green' : 'red'">
      {{company.profit}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your html :

`<td [style.positive]="company.profit > 0">`

and this to your css :

```
td.positive{
  background-color: green;
}
```